# Engineer accountability and code review processes

Tags: process, tdd, agile, scrum

In your “enterprise” work environment, how are engineers held accountable for performing code inspections and unit testing?  What processes do you follow (formal methodology or custom process) to ensure the quality of your software?  Do you or have you tried implementing a developer "signoff" sheet for deliverables?

Thanks in advance!

Update:  I forgot to mention we are using Code Collaborator to perform our inspections.  The problem is getting people to "get it" and buy into doing them outside of a core group of people.  As stalbot pointed out below it is a cultural change but the question becomes, how do you change your culture to promote quality initiatives such as reviews/unit tests?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to ensure that every changelist gets reviewed, *before* checkin,** then you could have your source control tool reject unreviewed checkins.  For example, a trigger could reject checkins without "CodeReview: " in the checkin comment.  Although people could still lie, they could also be held accountable.

**If you want to ensure that every changelist gets reviewed, *after* checkin,** then you could see if Code Collaborator will play nicely with your source control system and automatically make a review task after each checkin (push or pull; whatever works).  After that, use whatever "polite annoyance" features Code Collaborator has, to make sure reviews actually get *done*.

**If you want people to review *only some* checkins, not *all* checkins,** then good luck with that.

Comment: Actually it's better than that for before-check-in review, since you're using Code Collaborator.  There's a built-in feature that causes the version control server to ask Collaborator whether it's OK to check in.  You can't lie -- the review either exists and is done or not.

Answer (score 5):

• Our company uses peer code reviews. We conduct them as Over-The-Shoulder reviews and invite the team’s tester to participate in the meeting to gain a better understanding of the changes. We use Source Control software that requires check-in, code-review rules to be signed off.  Nothing big, just another developer's name that has reviewed the code.

• There are definite benefits to code review as several studies have been able to demonstrate. For our company, it was evident that code quality increased as the number of support calls decreased and the number of reported bugs decreased as well. NOTE: Some of the benefits here were the result of implementing Scrum and abandoning Waterfall. More on Scrum below.

• The benefits of code review can be a more stable product, more maintainable code as it applies to structure and coding standards, and it allows developers to focus more on new features rather than “fire-fighting” bugs, and other production issues. There really aren’t any drawbacks if code reviews are conducted “right”. More on the “right way” below.

• Some of the hurdles to overcome while implementing code reviews are the idea that “big brother” is watching me and the idea that not having perfect code means torture and pain. Getting developers to trust each other is difficult sometimes, especially when it involves “pecking order” or the “holier than thou” attitudes and putting your hard work under a microscope. Trust is the key to resolving these issues. A developer must trust that they will not be punished by peers or management for mistakes in code. It happens to everyone. Make a note of the issue, get it resolved and move on.

**Scrum** 
One of the benefits of using the Scrum methodology is that a development cycle (”sprint”) is short. The time-frame of the “sprint” is determined by what works best for your organization and will need some trial and error, but really shouldn’t be longer than four week iterations. The benefit is that it requires the developers communicate daily and communicate problems early on in the project. This was initially adopted by our development department and has spread to all areas of our company as the benefits of scrum are far reaching. For more information, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCRUM or http://www.scrumalliance.org/ . As the development iterations are smaller, the code review process reviews smaller pieces of code, making the review more likely to find problems than hours or days of formal reviews.

**“Right Way”** 
Code Reviews done the “right way” is completely subjective. However, I personally believe that they should be informal, over-the-shoulder reviews. All of the participants in a review should avoid personally attacking the person being reviewed with statements such as “why did you do it that way?” or “what were you thinking?” etc. These types of comments diminish the trust between peers, leading to animosity, hours of arguing over the best/right way to code a solution. Keep in mind that developers do not think or code exactly the same, and there are many solutions to a problem.
Just a little clarification on over-the-shoulder reviews; these can be conducted via remote desktop sharing (pick flavor here), or in person. However, they shouldn’t be limited to the developers only. We typically invite our entire scrum team which consists of two developers per team, a tester, a documentation person, and product owner. All non-developers are there to gain a better understanding of the changes or new functionality being made. They are free to ask questions or provide input, but not to make coding decisions or comments. This has been effective as certain questions will be asked that may change the direction of the project as the initial requirements may have missed a scenario, but that is what agile is all about, change.

**Suggestion** 
I would highly recommend researching scrum and code reviews, before mandating them. Create the basic rules for each and implement them as part of your culture to achieve a better quality product. It must become part of your culture so that it is part of a natural process and integrated at all levels, as it is a paradigm shift from poor quality, missed deadlines and frustration to better quality products, less frustration, and more on-time deliverables.

Comment: this is useful information, however we are struggling with the "make it part of your culture" part as you cant just force a cultural change.  The problems you have listed are true but the fact remains that people just aren't performing the inspections...

Comment: The cultural shift is the most difficult thing to establish.  To accomplish this, you might want to stress the benefits of not being in fire-fighting mode, and quality work equals quality products.  Some how you need to instill a desire to become better.  You should also establish a quality measure.

Answer (score 2):

We have a pretty cool setup.  Coders are expected to test their code before check-ins to ensure that it doesn't break the build and to write tests where they make sense to have but high coverage isn't required.

Complex methods are expected to be commented.

At the end of phases code is reviewed by the whole team.

Answer (score 2):

Pair programming. Work items have a required field of collaborator, the person that you paired with for the work

Answer (score 1):

We lean heavily on ITIL concepts. While we don't need the full scale ITSM that ITIL provides, we have implemented processes that draw from some of the best practices in ITIL, specifically in the areas of Change Management and Release Management.

Code reviews are part of our RM strategy. As a change or new piece of code makes its way through our RM process, a lot of eyes look at it. Ultimately the Release Manager makes the call on approval or rework, and all of this is documented (we use TFS and SharePoint). Formal code reviews are held by the Release Manager and the technical team he selects. The primary developer for a release candidate is held accountable for adherence to standards, functionality, and a verification of a completed test plan. If the quality standards aren't met, the deliverable is rejected and the project schedule is updated to reflect the rework.

Yes, this is all very heavy. I work in government and we have complex laws to follow, specifically in the areas of taxes, ADA compliance, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

We use three basic rules

1) The developer is responsible for fixing bugs in code when unit tests don't exist. In cases where there is a test, the person breaking the test is responsible for fixing it.

2) Code reviews. There are some code review smells that are a good warning sign, over defensiveness and blame redirection being the two most common.

3) NO EMAILING CODE, JARs or config files. Everything is in the scm.

Answer (score 0):

To create the culture 1st try define your standards and values and most of all make them known.

Then hire people who believe in them or who could be able to adapt to them. Don't hire someone who does not have any connection at all with your company values.

Make sure that those who respect these values and show improvements are "rewarded" and "properly" recognized and seen as models. Don't forget that for many is not all about the money.

Don't hesitate to take appropriate measures againts those who do not fulfill their responsibilities but make sure they know them. And have them accountable for their deeds.
Allow people to become used with any new responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

To make change in culture is big deal. Still there are some ways to change.

1. Create awareness about  code review and importance of code review tool. It can be done using training session.
2. Motivate the people : Giving some reward for the code reviews.
3. Change in process : Make sure that code review should be happen and properly. It can be done using checklist and part of release process.
4. Do not try to change completely. Slowly introduce newer changes. Create small group to observe and discuss the change in code review process.
5. Provide the solution instead of create problem. Process should not be overhead. It comes automatically. Provide solutions to peoples problem related to the process.